# angular testing a component using jasmine when the a method call is made in the html

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have to test this odd situation. In my html i have:

```
    <div id="date">
      <h5>
        {{ showFormattedDate(myDate) }}
      </h5>
    </div>
```

The function `showFormattedDate()` is defined in `.ts` as follows:

```
  showFormattedDate(dateToFormat: string): string {
    return moment(dateToFormat).format('HH:mm DD/M/YYYY');
  }
```

Now i'm trying to test this but i keep getting this error:

> Expected ' Created at Invalid date ' to be '12:23 29/5/2020'.

The invalid date part is also what i see for a split of a second on the screen when the page loads but that is because the function call, i think.

I've tried testing it using these two ways:

```
  it('should display the date correctly', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // await fixture.whenStable();
    // await fixture.isStable();
    // await fixture.whenRenderingDone();

    expect(el.query(By.css('#date')).nativeElement.textContent).toContain(
      getTestData().date);
  });

  it('should display the date correctly (async)', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      // wait for async getQuote
      fixture.detectChanges(); // update view with quote
      expect(el.query(By.css('#date')).nativeElement.textContent).toContain(getTestData().date);
    });
  }));
```

But both return the aforementioned error. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a method within a template expression is considered bad practice in angular.So you may want to avoid that first.

Read [this](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) for more details on that.

You can make use of Angular Pipe here which will which will transform your date to your desired format and you can test the transform method of your pipe.

For more details on usage of Angular pipe click [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) and to know how to test your angular pipe here is a good [article](https://www.amadousall.com/angular-pipes-unit-testing-angular-pipes/) for the same.

Comment: I wanted to use MomentJS so i don't have to fiddle with dates but it seems that i need to if i were to use the pipe?

Comment: you can move your date logic u have here into the transform method of your pipe

Comment: Have you done this before? I just went through the process of making my own pipe and again, it works in the page but i get an error. 

Error: The pipe 'customDate' could not be found!

So any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you generate your pipe using angular ng command ? `ng generate pipe <your pipe name>`

Comment: thats the right way, do u see the entry of your pipe class within `app.module.ts` within declaration array?

Comment: Yes it is there, it is also imported correctly (looking at the path and clicking on it takes me to the folder)